# JQSlickWrap doesn't work with modern browsers

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use JQSlickWrap, I have all .js files required and Jquery files as well. but still it doesn't work with modern browsers like Chrome. I have tested many canvas example and other html5 examples in this browsers and they all work fine.

Edit: Added my code

```
<head>
    <title>jQSlickWrap Demo 3</title>
    <script src="./jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script src="./jquery.slickwrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .wrapReady {
            float: left;
            padding: 30px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.wrapReady').slickWrap({
                bgColor: {              // use red as the background color
                    r: 255,
                    g: 0,
                    b: 0,
                    a: 255
                },
                cutoff: 10,             // let there be a tolerance of 10
                resolution: 15,         // create divs of height 15
                bloomPadding: false     // let's not use bloom
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="me.jpg" class="wrapReady" />

    <p>Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..
    Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..Lots of text goes here..</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Would you mind posting an example of code that isn't working?

Comment: Are/were you running this code from your local machine by opening the file in a browser, or were you serving the html up via a server?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the jQuery library loaded in anywhere. Try loading it in before the slick wrap script. That should solve your problem.

Comment: good call. unfortunately the OP didn't format his code correctly and the script tag was hidden